# How to get number of all elements in values of dictionary, where is value is a list, give the int number python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the values are lists, and I would like to know how many elements in lists associated with each key. I've found here this one. But I need total number of elements only for one key. for example for

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_dict = {'I': [23,24,23,23,24], 'P': [17,23,23,17,24,12]}
>>> {k: Counter(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{'P': Counter({17: 2, 23: 2, 24: 1, 12: 1}), 'I': Counter({23: 3, 24: 2})}
```

For example `{P:6}`, will be better if it give just number, `count_elements=5`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> my_dict= {'I':[23,24,23,23,24],'P':[17,23,23,17,24,12]}
>>> {k: len(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{'I': 5, 'P': 6}
```

A single key is simple:

```
>>> len(my_dict['P'])
6
```

As @Joe suggested `len(my_dict.get(key, []))` works when a key doesn't exist, which potentially works, but then you can't distinguish between keys with empty lists, and keys that don't exist. You can catch the `KeyError`  here in that case.

Comment: Thanks, but It give me keyError: P ? In both case

Answer (score 2):

This will get the number of values for the given key `key`. I believe that's what the question asked.

```
my_dict= {"I":[23,24,23,23,24],"P":[17,23,23,17,24,12]}
number = len(my_dict.get(key, []))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you had in mind?

```
my_dict= {'I':[23,24,23,23,24],'P':[17,23,23,17,24,12]}
print {k:len(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
{'I': 5, 'P': 6}
```